# Change Order For Chart Series Collection VBA Code

Tags: vba

I am using the Excel 2013

I have to change in select data the Specify Order For Series collection in Select Data for Chart

`=SERIES([Series Name],[X Values],[Y Values],[Plot Order])`

I have to change the "Holder" series collection from 5th to 1st move (Chart Right Click in Select Data)

[image: 1]

I actually did something similar. I put `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).PlotOrder = 1` for the first data series, but it doesn't work that way.

My VBA code not work, what I am wrong that I don't know...

enclosed the file and requirements as per the image

Kindly correction the VBA code

Thanks for Help....

Comment: Are all series on the primary axis? Each axis has its own list of plot orders. In the series formula, [PlotOrder] is really more like [SeriesIndex], meaning the order it was added to the chart.

Answer (score 2):

This simple macro reverses the order of series in the active chart:

```
Sub ReorderSeries()
  Dim SeriesNumber As Long
  For SeriesNumber = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(SeriesNumber).PlotOrder = 1
  Next
End Sub
```

But if you want to change the order of series in the legend, it only works if all series are of the same type and all on the same axis. I wrote about this in [Order of Series and Legend Entries in Excel Charts](https://peltiertech.com/order-series-legend-entries-excel-charts/).